# How to redirect in .htaccess? => /ua/ to /?lang=ua

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a multilingual website and .htaccess, which displays the ***all page*** and ***language*** *?lang=ua* style.

I want to redirect (using code 301) asks **site.com/en/** to **site.com/?lang=en** with RewriteEngine.

Example:

```
site.com/en/               => site.com/?lang=en
site.com/ua/news.html      => site.com/news.html?lang=ua
site.com/ua/news/2-material-two.html => site.com/news/2-material-two.html?lang=ua
and so on much...
```

How to prepare Htaccess file for Apache to meet this criterion? And how do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you should ask this question in server fault.

Answer (score 1):

Put this code in your .htaccess file under DOCUMENT_ROOT dir:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)$ /$2?lang=$1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

Comment: This is a good solution also, but it doesn't allow for further levels of directories as every directory level requires a separate rewrite rule this way. If there are a number of levels, it is better to use a more dynamic method

Comment: @FluffyKitten: Check the answer now, its totally generic and works for all the test cases in OP.

Comment: Neat solution. I'm going to upvote it because its neater than my quickly-thrown together one! Just a couple of things: I'd add the NC code also, otherwise it is case sensitive, and I'd include RewriteOptions MaxRedirects=10 - just in case something goes wrong it will prevent infinite looping. @Areku_UA you should accept this solution, it rewards anubhava with reputation and also gives you an accepted answer rating while will encourage others to answer future questions you may have.

Comment: Hello, anubhava! I came here. And tried your answer. But failed. The error output - `http://site.com/ru/news?lang=ru&lang=ru&lang=ru&lang=ru&lang=ru&lang=ru&lang=ru&‌​lang=ru&lang=ua&lang=ru` => Need `http://site.com/?lang=ru`. I myself tried to change your answer. Again did not work. I do not really know only a redirect. I think that you need to add `RewriteCond% {QUERY_STRING} ...` You can change your answer? I'm waiting for an answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @anubhava i have a problem like this one, but it's exactly the opposite, i need to redirect `/?lang=en` to `/en`, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56764820/how-can-i-redirect-lang-en-to-en/56770413#56770413 here my post

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteOptions MaxRedirects=10

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule http://site.com/([^/]+)/(.+).html$ http://site.com/$2.html?lang=$1 [R=301,NC]
```

I've just put this together off the top of my head so it may not be quite right, but the idea is that it will examine the url and the `([^/]+)` should read the 1st directory, and then read everything up to the .html.

It then rewrites the url to be site.com/[everything after 1st dir up to .html].html?lang=[name of 1st dir]

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your htaccess file in the root of your domain

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#if the lang param is not present
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^lang=
#capture the language code and redirec to url with lang param
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/(.+\.html)$ /$2?lang=$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Hello, anubhava! I came here. And tried your answer. Everything works. Not quite right, but you need to remove the excess. That conclusion - `http://site.com/ua/material-1?lang=ru` => need to correct - `http://site.com/material-1.html?lang=ru` (to remove excess `/ua/` and add `.html`) you can fix? I do not know about the redirect. Waiting for an answer. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please, if you must use general "possibly directory matching"-rule, consider the !-d operator (and optional: the !-f operator).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/ http://site.com/?lang=$1 [R=301,L]
```

So you won't end up fixing all kinds of strange problems with existing files and/or directories.