# How can i redirect /?lang=en to /en?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, parameters

I'm having trouble redirecting a multilingual website one page. My redirection to htaccess doesn't operate properly. I need assistance with how this can be done. In my htaccess, when I add these two lines

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=en$
RewriteRule ^ /en? [R=301,L]
```

redirect working, but mysite.com/en show 404 not found. Someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your redirect rule as shown in question is working fine. Bot you also need a rewrite rule to handle `/en`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=([a-z]{2})$
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/?$ ?lang=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: its works for me, thanks, and i have additional 3 languages, how can i put all 3 for this code?

Comment: thank u very much mister, and my last question is, i have 3 languages in my website, russian, english and deutsch, so if i want to redirect russian language to `https://example.com`, without `ru`, what i supposed to add to this code? p.s deutsch and english should remain unchanged

Comment: @QuickBecko: That last requirement will require major changes in this answer. Please create a new question for `ru` requirement and I will surely attend it.

Answer (score 0):

If your browsers ends up at mysite.com/en, your redirection does work, so your question is not how to redirect, but why there's no content at /en on your site. You need to investigate that.